# html/css image issue inside div

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a landing page exactly like this (FYI, to work on my HTML/CSS skills, I have decided to exactly imitate this landing page just for practice!)

http://oi67.tinypic.com/b8qp8i.jpg

However, as you can see from what I did, the full background picture (sailing boat + ocean) does not show up in the first column: http://oi66.tinypic.com/o7ktgl.jpg

Another issue is that on the left side of the background image on the third column, I keep seeing on a small "broken page" icon (I don't know why it's there but it's really been annoying) ... is it an image problem or something wrong with the image file?

Help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Here is my full HTML and CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Your description goes here">
        <meta name="keywords" content="one, two, three">

        <title>Relaxr</title>

        <!-- external CSS link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainColumn">
            <header>
                <h1>Relaxr</h1>
                <h2>Get piece of mind with a single tap</h2>
            </header>

        <span>
            <button id="getButton">Get it Now</button>
        </span>
        </div>

        <div id="secondColumn">
            <header>
                <h1>Benefits</h1>
                <p>The perfect personal assistant. Relaxr does your job<br>for you so you can enjoy life as it is meant to be.</p>
                <ul class="benefitss">
                    <li>Schedule meetings for you</li>
                    <li>Excel automation to complete your <br>work for you</li>
                    <li>Responds to e-mails on your behalf</li>
                    <li>Does all yor work for you with our<br>revolutionary technology</li>
                </ul>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div id="thirdColumn">
            <img src="../images/testimonial_bg.jpg">
            <p>“Relaxr changed my life. I’ve been able<br> to travel the world, spend limited time<br> working and my boss keeps thanking<br>me for crushing work.”</p>
            <p>- Amanda, Intuit</p>
        </div>

        <div id="fourthColumn">
            <button id="signupButton">Sign Up Now!</button>
        </div>

        <div id="fifthColumn">
            <p>Relaxr</p>
            <div id="footer">
                <p>Copyright 2015. Relaxr.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/******************************************
/* SETUP
/*******************************************/

/* Box Model Hack */
* {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firexfox */
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android */
     box-sizing: border-box; /* IE */
}

/* Clear fix hack */
.clearfix:after {
     content: ".";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     line-height: 0;
     height: 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px; /* note the padding around a right floated image */
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0; /* note the padding around a left floated image */
}

/******************************************
/* BASE STYLES
/*******************************************/

body {
     color: #000;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 1.4;
     font-family: Open Sans;
     background: url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
     background-size: cover;
}


/******************************************
/* LAYOUT
/*******************************************/

/*MAIN COLUMN*/

#mainColumn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainColumn h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 80%
}

#mainColumn h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  height: 40%;
}

/*GET IT NOW BUTTON*/
#getButton {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 30px;
  width: 130px;
}

/*SECOND COLUMN*/

#secondColumn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: white;
}

#secondColumn h1 {
  padding-left: 65px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  color: navy;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#secondColumn p {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.benefitss {
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.benefitss li{
  padding-top: 2px;
} 

/*THIRD COLUMN*/
#thirdColumn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

#thirdColumn p:nth-child(2) {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#thirdColumn p:nth-child(3) {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

/*FOURTH COLUMN*/
#fourthColumn {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

/*SIGN UP BUTTON*/
#signupButton {
  background-color: #000040;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 800;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 42.9%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#fifthColumn {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  position: absolute;
}

#fifthColumn p {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
}


#footer p {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 11%;
}
```

Comment: Change from `center top` to `center center` in `background: url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;` ... for the "broken page" icon, find and remove the `img` element, as it source path appears to be broken

Comment: I tried changing it to center top but I see no changes after refreshing the page =/

Comment: I said to `center center`

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. I tried changing it to: background: url(../images/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;   but that did not do the trick, unfortunately.